# load large text using scrollbar event in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have large string which I need to write into QPlainTextEdit. but it is crashing due to large size,

I am trying to load string based on scroll event to avoid crash, if scrollbar goes to down than update qplaintextedit text.

any idea or info into following point

1. convert large string into buffer
2. update qplaintextedit based on scroll bar event so text updated as user moves down or upward

   ```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPlainTextEdit
    class PlainTextEdit(QPlainTextEdit):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(PlainTextEdit, self).__init__(parent)
            self.last_position = self.verticalScrollBar().sliderPosition()
            self.verticalScrollBar().sliderMoved.connect(self.handle_value_changed)

    def update_data(self):
        data = "test line \n"
        for i in range (0, 100, 1):
             data += data
        self.setPlainText(data)

    def handle_value_changed(self, position):
        if position > self.last_position:
            print("down")
        else:
            print("up")
        self.last_position = position




   if __name__ == "__main__":
        import sys
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        w = PlainTextEdit()
        w.update_data()
        w.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
   ```

Comment: That approach wouldn't be effective: the scroll bar range is based on the contents of the scroll area (or, in this case, the text). I'm afraid that there's no easy solution for this, as you'd probably need a custom QAbstractScrollArea and a QWidget subclass that would implement the layout and painting of a QTextDocument subclass. The only "simple" workaround I could think of is to split the file in "batches", and use an external interface that allows switching through those batches by dynamically reading the contents based on a given range.

Comment: any example info

Comment: or can i create like treeview structure inside qplaintextedit

Comment: can we solve this problem using pagination any idea or info